# NiFi Update Record escapeJson Record Path Not Working

Tags: json, apache-nifi

Say I have the following JSON message:
{
"test": 123,
"person": {
"age": 36
}
}

What I want is to add a new property to this message with the "person" path being converted to JSON String.
Per NiFi docs the "escapeJson" function can be used - https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html#escapejson

But it doesn't work - when I'm trying to use it in the UpdateRecord processor:
[image]

And receive the following error:

```
2021-10-25 17:00:29,413 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10] o.a.n.processors.standard.UpdateRecord UpdateRecord[id=b7a7a495-017c-1000-ba8a-b599dcffdeec] Failed to process StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=fb344cf4-397d-43a2-b1a1-eb0309b68d2c,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1635163177077-2, container=default, section=2], offset=47339, length=51],offset=0,name=d5a4b078-82dd-4d2b-ae1f-0ce236b2c20c,size=51]; will route to failure: org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.util.IllegalTypeConversionException: Cannot convert value [{"age":36}] of type class java.lang.String to Record for field personStringified
org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.util.IllegalTypeConversionException: Cannot convert value [{"age":36}] of type class java.lang.String to Record for field personStringified
    at org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.util.DataTypeUtils.toRecord(DataTypeUtils.java:403)
    at org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.util.DataTypeUtils.convertType(DataTypeUtils.java:220)
    at org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.util.DataTypeUtils.convertType(DataTypeUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.nifi.json.WriteJsonResult.writeValue(WriteJsonResult.java:327)
    at org.apache.nifi.json.WriteJsonResult.writeRecord(WriteJsonResult.java:199)
    at org.apache.nifi.json.WriteJsonResult.writeRecord(WriteJsonResult.java:148)
    at org.apache.nifi.serialization.AbstractRecordSetWriter.write(AbstractRecordSetWriter.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor791.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

I wonder whether there any sort of issue in NiFi itself? Why is it not able to introduce a new String field?

Could please anyone suggest?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like it’s already stringified. Remove the escapejson call and check.

Comment: No it's not - it just copies object while I need escaped JSON string:

Comment: Can you share the schema you are using in JsonTreeReader and JsonRecordSetWriter? I think using JOLT best and simple solution for this.

Comment: It's all in the question (JSON message).

Answer (score 0):

The personStringified field should be defind in a avro schema for the jsonTreeReader.

```
{
"type": "record",
"name": "TestObject",
"namespace": "ca.dataedu",
"fields": [{
    "name": "person",
    "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Person",
        "fields": [{
            "name": "age",
            "type": "int"
        }]
    }
}, {
    "name": "personStringified",
    "type": "string"
}, {
    "name": "test",
    "type": ["null", "int"],
    "default": null
}]
```

}

Output:

```
[{"person":{"age":36},"personStringified":"{\"age\":36}","test":123}]
```